# Priority of network connections

Tags: networking, internet, routing

I have a laptop with win7 and a LAN connection and a HSPA connection..

I need to set it up so that all internet traffic goes through the HSPA and never through LAN connection which also has Internet connectivity.. anyone knows how to do it properly?

Comment: Please read our FAQ - this question is more suitable for our sister site superuser.com.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections\
2. In the connection properties select TCP/IP 4 or 6 depending what you use and select `Properties` again
3. Bottom Right click `Advanced`
4. Untick `Automatic Metric` in the bottom
5. Set a number for each of the connections between 1 and 9999 where the smaller the number the higher the connection priority.

Answer (score 1):

Lower the interface metric. See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894564).